# How to use \<lang>inline| | within caption command (minted)

Tags: minted

I have read the `minted` package docs from `texdoc minted` terminal prompt. It states that I can define the `\cppinline||` command as:

[image]
[image]

So I have next code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[cachedir=minted_cache, newfloat=true]{minted}
\newmintinline{cpp}{}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
     \begin{figure}
         \begin{center}
             figure
         \end{center}
         \caption{Some code stuff --- \mintinline{cpp}|int foo(double bar)|}
     \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces the:

[image]

If I use the new `\cppinline||` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[cachedir=minted_cache, newfloat=true]{minted}
\newmintinline{cpp}{}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

     \begin{figure}
         \begin{center}
             figure
         \end{center}
         \caption{Some code stuff --- \cppinline|int foo(double bar)|}
     \end{figure}
     
\end{document}
```

I get the errors:

```
pr.tex|20 error| Argument of \FVExtraUnexpandedReadStarOArgBVArg has an extra }.
pr.tex|| Runaway argument?
pr.tex|20 error| Paragraph ended before \FVExtraUnexpandedReadStarOArgBVArg was complete.
```

`minted` docs say that minted has been designed in such a way that it should not conflict with `\caption` command:

[image]

Actually the `minted` docs have the source code for `\newmintinline`:

[image]

I can see the `\FVExtraReadOArgBeforeVArg` here that appears in the error message. But I don't understand anything. Is there a workaround to use the `\cppinline` in captions?  Bothering moment is that the `\mintinline` command works inside caption.

Comment: Try `\DeclareRobustCommand*{\cppinline}{\mintinline{cpp}}`, but note that it is not the same like a command defined by `\cppinline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands created with `\newmintinline`, like `\cppinline`, follow the same rules as `\mintinline`. They can often be used within other commands (such as `\caption`), but must use curly braces `{}` as code delimiters when used in movable arguments (such as within `\caption`).  Try replacing `\cppinline|int foo(double bar)|` with `\cppinline{int foo(double bar)}`.

In this particular case, `\mintinline` does appear to function with `|...|` code delimiters. However, this is actually due to a [bug in `fvextra`](https://github.com/gpoore/fvextra/issues/22). The `.aux` file contains incorrect information when `{}` delimiters are not used, so `\listoffigures` will not be correct.